# Ruby 1.9.3-p0 Passenger "Symbol not found: _ruby_current_thread"

Tags: ruby, passenger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails 3.1 and Ruby 1.9.3p125: ruby-debug19 still crashes with “Symbol not found: _ruby_threadptr_data_type”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442200/rails-3-1-and-ruby-1-9-3p125-ruby-debug19-still-crashes-with-symbol-not-found)

Just updated to 1.9.3-p0, updated all my gems and whatnot, but my application still cannot start.

Passenger error:

```
Error message:
dlopen(/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle,
9): Symbol not found: _ruby_current_thread Referenced from:
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug-base19-    0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle 
Expected in: flat namespace in /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle - /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle

Exception class: LoadError
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a problem with ruby-debug. Look here for a possible fix:
http://blog.wyeworks.com/2011/11/1/ruby-1-9-3-and-ruby-debug

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not installing dev gems (like `ruby-debug`) on your server anyway.

```
group :development do
  gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
end
```

Then in your capistrano file, just use.

```
# bundler bootstrap
require 'bundler/capistrano'
```

This skips anything inside the "development" and "test" groups.